# Introspection Query is invalid for buildClientSchema

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to convert from an introspection query to a GraphQL schema using the npm GraphQL library.

It keeps stating:

```
devAssert.mjs:7 Uncaught Error: Invalid or incomplete introspection result. Ensure that you are passing "data" property of introspection response and no "errors" was returned alongside: { ... }
```

Issue is I am getting it directly from GraphiQL Shopify and can't figure out how to validate my introspection return is correct.

Code:

```
var introspection = `
{
  "data": {
    "__schema": {
      "types": [
        {
          "name": "Boolean"
        },
        {
          "name": "String"
        },
        {
          "name": "QueryRoot"
        },
        {
          "name": "Job"
        },
        {
          "name": "ID"
        },
        {
          "name": "Node"
        },
        {
          "name": "Order"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cost": {
      "requestedQueryCost": 2,
      "actualQueryCost": 2,
      "throttleStatus": {
        "maximumAvailable": 1000,
        "currentlyAvailable": 980,
        "restoreRate": 50
      }
    }
  }
}`;

      let schema = buildClientSchema(introspection);
      //console.log(schema.printSchema());
```

I thought the introspection result could be a string? Or is there not enough info to build a schema? Do I need to expand the number of fields? What's the bare minimum needed to exchange an introspection result into a schema?

Comment: @DanStarns It wasn't a careless edit...it had backticks already.

Comment: I have tried it as a string. I thought backticks/template literals were a form of string. also toString() conversion and just standard `'` to no luck

Comment: @DanStarns my code had backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getIntrospectionQuery` to get the complete introspection query needed. If the response you're working with is a string, it should then be parsed to an object before being passed to `buildClientSchema` -- the function accepts an object, not a string.

Here's an example directly querying a schema using the `graphql` function -- you'll need to modify it based on how you're actually executing the query.

```
const { getIntrospectionQuery, buildClientSchema, graphql } = require('graphql')

const schema = new GraphQLSchema(...)
const source = getIntrospectionQuery()
const { data } = await graphql({ source, schema })
const clientSchema = buildClientSchema(data)
```

Make sure that you are only passing in the `data` portion of the response. The object you pass in should look like this:

```
{
  __schema: {
    // ...more properties
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh I was looking at `buildSchema` in the docs it says string `functionbuildSchema(source: string | Source): GraphQLSchema {`
so you need the full introspection query to be able to generate the schema? Makes sense but double checking.

Comment: but this requires me to have the schema already. What I want to do is take a string of the result from some outside source (say a text input) and output a schema...

Comment: You need the introspection result from running the query you get by running `getIntrospectionQuery`. This result needs to be an object, not a string. The object should have a single property (`__schema`). You don't **have** to use `getIntrospectionQuery` -- you can copy and paste the query from [the source code](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/getIntrospectionQuery.js).

Comment: yup! I understand now! giving it a try!

Comment: And like I said in the answer, I was using the `graphql` function just to demonstrate the concept. If you have a string of the result already, just parse it using `JSON.parse` and then pass that to `buildClientSchema`.

Comment: well, I put the generated query into Shopify's GraphiQL and then got back a proper validated JSON. However, still not working with `buildClientSchema` throws `Error` but doesn't tell me what except `devAssert`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/w0HgGMBV <-- here is the result from introspection quer from shopify. can't tell what's wrong or missing.

Comment: You can't just pass in that response if that's what you're doing. Like I said, the object you pass in has to have a single property (__schema). So you need to pass just that in (no `data`, no `extensions`, etc.). I just ran it locally (all 77,000 lines!) and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Edited answer to provide additional clarification

Comment: Ah! wild! I wasn't hitting it with a client. I assumed GraphiQL just returns the response as GraphQL sees didn't realize I had extra info! Thank you for taking the time to help a newcomer to GraphQL

Comment: @KyleCalica-St No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if it is correct.

Comment: In my case, the introspection was saved into `schema.json` file. I was able to run `buildClientSchema` by parsing the file as JSON, and then passing `data` property of JSON as an argument to the function.